# How do I install NumPy under Windows 8.1?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I install NumPy under Windows 8.1 ?
Similar questions/answers on `overflow` hasn't helped.

[image]

Comment: You mean `pip install numpy` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

and as you are using pyCharm you can go to:

1. ctrl-alt-s
2. click "project:projet name"
3. click project interperter
4. double click pip
5. search numpy from the top bar
6. click on numpy
7. click install package button

and if it doesnt work : [check this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: Your suggestion works fine. Is there a better/more sophisticated IDE for Python than PyCharm; which one do you use ?

Comment: I mostly use VScode. But pyCharm is also a good option if your machine is fast.