# GTK module not found in Python (PyCharm)

Tags: python, module, pycharm, gtk

How can I avoid the following error:

GTK module not found in Python (PyCharm), please see the snippet below.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71894114/how-do-i-install-numpy-under-windows-8-1/71894166#comment127042966_71894166) answer hasn't helped.
(Still cannot find gtk in pip.)

[image]

Comment: is the module installed?

Comment: What's your version of python?

Comment: @debugger `from gi.repository import Gtk` writes `from gi.repository import Gtk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'`

Comment: @debugger I'm using `Python 3.10`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pyhon 3.0+ then import this library like this: `from gi.repository import Gtk`